# Fermat last theorem

Tags: number-theory

Can someone please give the original paper by Prof. Wiles of the [proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiles%27_proof_of_Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem#Wiles.27_proof) of Fermat's Last Theorem? I cannot find it.

Comment: Look at the references of the wikipedia page you cited.

Comment: Good luck understanding the first few sentences. :D

Comment: Conjecture: Any person unable to find Wiles' proof will be unable to understand it.

Comment: @Charles
That's my problem. What's yours?

Comment: @x.y.z... re. Charles. On this site you will come across (rarely. thank God)  those who think that a question is far beneath them. Yet, instead of ignoring said questions such individuals are inclined to fire off a derogatory comment. Thankfully, most here are far better behaved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here it is!

I hope this might be what you are looking for.

http://math.stanford.edu/~lekheng/flt/wiles.pdf

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much.

Comment: `You don't have permission to access /~lekheng/flt/wiles.pdf on this server.` ooh I was so close understanding it.

Comment: Got an error 404, :(